# Convert elements of a matrix into floating numbers

Tags: python, string

Here's the output of data_1 that I'm working on:

```
print(data_1)  

[['1.0' '1.585' '1.78']
 ['1.0' '1.908' '1.816']
 ['1.0' '1.7' '1.732']
 ..., 
 ['1.0' '1.046' '4.824']
 ['1.0' '1.138' '4.874']
 ['1.0' '1.016' '5']]
```

I tried to convert the elements into floating numbers by simply using this code:

```
data_2 = float(data_1)
```

But instead I got the following error

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I convert the elements of this matrix into float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a numpy array, `float` is a base python function that only accepts scalar as parameter, i.e, it can only convert a scalar to float. For numpy array, there is a built in `astype` function you can use for type conversion:

```
data_1.astype(float)
# array([[ 1.   ,  1.585,  1.78 ],
#        [ 1.   ,  1.908,  1.816],
#        [ 1.   ,  1.7  ,  1.732],
#        [ 1.   ,  1.046,  4.824],
#        [ 1.   ,  1.138,  4.874],
#        [ 1.   ,  1.016,  5.   ]])
```